# Passing mongoose model to ejs and rendering in script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I'm returning my model to my view something like this:

```
User.findOneById('xxx', function(err, result){
    res.render('viewName', {user: result});
}
```

Then, on my view, I have a script block, that I'm trying to assign the `user` to a variable:

```
<script id="foundBusiness" type="text/javascript">
    var user = <%-user%>
</script>
```

This renders as follows as the HTML

```
var user = { __v: 0,
  _id: 5315b7b9caaf52e624070002,
  firstName: 'Alex',
  lastName: 'Brown',
  password: '$2a$10$Zs/6JmB3Rq5dddHvjZNUse9vl.8z3hJO.LUGBqMEE.vBMk4lVuav.'}
```

My issue is around the `_id` field
This is obviously not valid Javascript, and as such, an error occurs:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the horse's mouth

> ObjectIds contain the raw MongoDB binary and don't work with templating so we provide the id convenience method to convert them to hexstrings

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/548

One possible solution -

```
User.findOneById('xxx', function(err, result){
    result._id = result._id.toHexString();
    res.render('viewName', {user: result});
}
```

I think assigning it to result.id would also work.

```
result._id = result.id;
```

Comment: ... so what can I do in my view?

Comment: You can reassign string representation of _id to itself before passing it to the template.

Comment: also, if i do    console.log(result.id);
   console.log(result._id); - they are exactly the same/

Comment: i ran JSON.stringify(result) around it in my view... that seems to of solved it

Comment: JSON.stringify will pass a string to the user variable and hence raise no error